# Monitor flickers and turns off after 1-2 seconds after connection to my laptop

Tags: display

I've an HP LP2065 that I connect to my laptop as an external display. It has been working very well over the past few days, but as of late, flickers slightly and turns off 1 or 2 seconds after I connect it.

Any idea on what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

FIrst suggestions would be to test the components in isolation.

- Test the monitor an a different computer / laptop
- Test the cable on a known working setup
- Test the Laptop with a known working monitor
- Check the power cable to the monitor on a known working monitor.

These basic troubleshooting steps should allow you to isolate which component is faulty.

Answer (score 0):

What I most probably think is that flicker can be due to:
Mismatch of refresh rate of Monitor settings from the laptop. Well testing the components in isolation is a good tip.

I've seen several monitors and laptops behaving erratically after being connected e.g. laptop loses it's resolution.

Also do check that the multiple display option for LCD and Monitors is set,

Resolution and Refresh rate are two key points.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, same monitor model. For me, the same thing happens no matter which computer I plug in, no matter which cable, no matter which monitor input I use. So it's pretty much certainly the monitor hardware.

From some knowledgeable-sounding folks on the Reddit thread below say that for the bulbs to fail is fairly common on HP monitors. You can replace them yourself, but it's a significant amount of work, requires soldering, heatshrinking rubber wraps, etc.

https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/100uty/trying_to_fix_a_hp_lp2065_displays_for_2_seconds/